# How to connect about 50 Bosch BNO055 sensors to one RasPi 3?

Tags: gpio, sensor, i2c

I am building an IMU system that needs to have about 50 9DOF [BNO055](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/products/all_products/bno055) sensors.

BNO055 supports **0x28 (default)** and **0x29** as address over I2C.

Is there a way I can connect about 50 9DOF sensors to one RasPi 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use I2C multiplexors.

Typically each multiplexor lets you connect 8 devices.  Typically multiplexors can be assigned 8 different addresses so you can connect 8 multiplexors to an I2C bus.

This means you can have 64 devices with the same address connected to an I2C bus.

For a typical I2C multiplexor see

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use I2C multiplexer. [PCS9547 I2C mux](https://www.controleverything.com/content/MUX?sku=PCA9547_I2CMUX) is one of the best option. its a 1:8 mux so you can connect 16 BNO55 to one PCA9547 and then use 3 more mux to connect total 64. Using I2C mux really easy, all you will need to do is call particular port and then talk to the device attached to that port.
this PCA9547 mux board has on power power management so you wont need any external power source and it has 3 address lines so you can connect total 8 of these to one I2C master device. so in your case you can connect upto 128 BNO55.

Answer (score 0):

The BNO055 has a selectable address (0x28 or 0x29).

From the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf):

```
The default I²C address of the BNO055 device is 0101001b (0x29). The alternative address
0101000b (0x28), in I2C mode the input pin COM3 can be used to select between the
primary and alternative I2C
```

So, another option is to have (by default) all sensors at address 0x28 (all COM3 pins LOW) and then use an IO pin to drive the chosen sensors COM3 pin HIGH and do all your I2C for address 0x29.

This would need 50 IO pins, so you'd still need something like 3* MCP23017 devices.